# Trigger an Auto launch flow when a record is deleted

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, visual-flows, flowsupport

I want to trigger an auto launch flow when any record is deleted. It works fine when a record is edited and created which is invoked from the process builder. My auto launch contains a pause element so I cannot invoke from a record triggered flow. I simply want to trigger auto launch when any record is deleted. Can anyone please share the best approach ?

Thanks

Comment: why would there need to be a pause element in a record-triggered flow on delete?  can you refactor?

Comment: Hi @cropredy, I was using the Get Record element in the flow loop. I know it's not good practice to use the Get Record element or any DML operation within the loop. I was using the pause element to reset the flow limits. I just simply need to call the flow when any record is deleted.

Thanks

Comment: I'll ask the question again - can you refactor the flow to not use Pause?  If not, you'll need to delegate to apex invocable that in turn delegates to a queueable to get higher limits.

Comment: Thanks @cropredy, I'll try the invocable method. I cannot refactor the flow not to use the Pause element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the flow can't be refactored to avoid the Pause element, you'll need to delegate the delete operation to something else that can execute delete operations

- Invocable Apex
- Invocable Apex that in turn delegates to an @future or Queueable (async)
- Publish a Platform Event whose subscriber trigger/flow does the delete (this will be async)